# How do you tell IntelliJ to use the Oracle JDK instead of the Adopt Open JDK?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-17, adoptopenjdk

I am running [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac) on a [Mac M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M2) architecture.  I initially downloaded JDK 17 from Adopt Open JDK and created a simple Kotlin project that prints "hello world" from provided sample code within the IDE as shown below:

[image]

However, I am getting this error message when trying to build this simple hello world project:

```
Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
Unable to download toolchain matching these requirements: {languageVersion=8, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}
Unable to download toolchain. This might indicate that the combination (version, architecture, release/early access, ...) for the requested JDK is not available.
Could not read 'https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/8/ga/mac/aarch64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk' as it does not exist.
```

The error message is definitely true as when I copy and paste the URL:

https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/8/ga/mac/aarch64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk

and put in a web browser, the site does not exist.  So it makes sense why IntelliJ can't read the site.

So I downloaded the [Oracle JDK 17 for M2 Apple](https://download.oracle.com/java/17/archive/jdk-17.0.6_macos-aarch64_bin.dmg) instead and pointed the IntelliJ project to look at where it was installed as shown below:

[image]

[image]

However, IntelliJ seems to be stuck on using Adopt Open JDK despite the fact that I'm telling it to use Oracle JDK 17.  How do I get IntelliJ to use the Oracle JDK and look for the Adopt JDK instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24695/Default-Kotlin-project-can-not-be-synced-on-Mac-M1).

The solution is to either update to IntelliJ IDEA 2023+ (currently [available as RC](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)) or to change `jvmToolchain(8)` in `build.gradle.kts` to `jvmToolchain(11)`.